# Monitoring kubernetes pod readiness in stackdriver

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

With stackdriver's kubernetes engine integration, I can view real-time information on my pods and services, including how many are ready. I can't find any way to monitor this, however.

Is there a way to set up an alerting policy that triggers if no pods in a deployment or service are ready? I can set up a log-based metric, but this seems like a crude workaround for information that stackdriver logging seems to already have access to.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the  Stackdriver support of this feature; however, you can try creating following alerts as a workaround:

1. In Alerting policy creation user interface, select resource type as
   "k8s_container", also select a metric that always exists ( for
   example, 'CPU usage time').
2. Define any "filter" or you can use "group by" which will trigger the alert conditions.
3. In aggregation, choose "count" aggregator.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Kubernetes metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes) documentation there doesn't seems to be such metric in place.

It does however look like a potential [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).